# Unity C# - Throwing a child object away from a parent object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to 'throw' a specific child object from my parent object (i.e. like a ball) when an Input is pressed. I've got my player picking up a ball and making it a child of it's own (and moving with it), but I am unable to get the throw functionality working. Here is my code: Please note the '/////' in the Update function, that's where I believe the code would go? I may be wrong. I've tried several things to no avail.

```
public static float playerDistance;
bool hasGarbage;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    transform.Translate(h * Time.deltaTime * 5f, 0f, 5f * Time.deltaTime);
    playerDistance = transform.localPosition.z;


    if (hasGarbage == true)
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        }
    }

}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Garbage")
    {

        other.transform.parent = transform;
        hasGarbage = true;


    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should consider creating a [Fixed Joint](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-FixedJoint.html) instead of actually parenting the ball under the player. When you need to throw the ball, just break the joint before applying any force to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using AddForce().  This should add force to the direction specified.

Here is the unity documentation:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html

Here is an example of it in action:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBDWTjn05eg